# What makes an OS X app not open with the error "LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810"?

Tags: macos, app-bundle

I am working on what should be a very simple application bundle for OS X. My OS is version 10.7.5. The app in this case is a shell script.

[Kerkerkruip.app/Contents/Info.plist](https://github.com/i7/kerkerkruip/blob/master/packages/osx/Kerkerkruip.app/Contents/Info.plist):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>Kerkerkruip</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>Kicon.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>org.kerkerkruip.Kerkerkruip</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Kerkerkruip</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <!--<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>-->
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>9.0.1</string>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>10.4</string>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>© 2011-2015 by the Kerkerkruip team</string>
    <!--<key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>MainMenu</string>-->
    <!--<key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>-->
</dict>
</plist>
```

[Kerkerkruip.app/Contents/MacOS/Kerkerkruip](https://github.com/i7/kerkerkruip/blob/master/packages/osx/Kerkerkruip.app/Contents/MacOS/Kerkerkruip):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "This is a blank script." 1>&2
exit 1
```

When I try to  open the app I get the following error message:

```
$ open Kerkerkruip.app/
The application cannot be opened because it has an incorrect executable format.
```

The script is set +x. I have seen [this question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/145675) but nothing there helped - my script is over 27 characters.

Edit: After following the instructions [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16546673/2854284) to rebuild the Launch Services database for my app, trying to open it now produces:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Users/dannii/Documents/kerkerkruip/packages/osx/Kerkerkruip.app.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some testing, and was able to reproduce your second error.

> LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /PATH/TO/Kerkerkruip.app.

After experimentation, it looks like the issue is caused by your shell script exiting with the error code of `1`. If you `exit` with the success code of `0`, the error does not occur.

### Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "This is a blank script." 1>&2
exit 0
```

Comment: Quite right, I feel rather dumb. That's what you get for copying code without thinking about it. But no commands in the script file display anything in the console window... I've tried a few stream redirecting options but they don't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Ah, I've discovered that the open command basically sends stdout to /dev/null. That's okay, I can make do.

Comment: You can change this `open` redirection from within your shell script to debug it with the construct: `exec 2 >/Users/dannii/...`.