# Why I can't Cmd-Tab to my application window on Mac OS X 10.9 after upgrading to XULRunner 33?

Tags: macos, xulrunner

I have a standalone XULRunner application that was previously running XULRunner 1.9.2 (old, I know).  I just upgraded to XULRunner 33.

Previously, When I was developing locally (MacBook Pro with Mac OS X 10.9.5), I would often <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> between my IDE and my application.

After the upgrade, I can no longer do this.  I still get a window on my desktop (as defined in `main.xul`), but it no longer appears in my <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> list.  I have to "find" it on the desktop.

Closing the window quits the application, etc., and the fact that I'm getting an application window at all implies that my `main.xul` is correct... but I don't know why this is.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://my-app-name/skin/css/main.css" type="text/css"?>
<!DOCTYPE window SYSTEM "chrome://my-app-name/locale/main.dtd">
<window id="main" title="&window-title;" width="750" height="530" persist="width,height,screenX,screenY,sizemode" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

  <script><!-- MY APPLICATION CODE HERE --></script>

  <keyset>
    <key modifiers="accel" key="W" oncommand="window.close()"/>
    <key modifiers="accel" key="Q" id="quit"/>
  </keyset>

  <toolbox>
    <menubar>
      <menu id="menu_file" label="File" hidden="true">
        <menupopup>
          <menuitem id="menu_FileQuitItem" key="quit" label="Quit" oncommand="goQuitApplication();"/>
        </menupopup>
      </menu>
    </menubar>
  </toolbox>
</window>
```

I've read through the [Windows and menus in XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/XULRunner/Windows_and_menus_in_XULRunner) tutorial:

The same code on XULRunner 1.9.2 runs fine and I can "activate" the window.  With the new XULRunner, the window title appears greyed out in Mac OS X and is not selectable.

Any ideas of what to try?

I don't know if it's helpful, but I also used to get a menu bar in OS X as well, when the window was selected.  Even now if I click on the window's title bar, the menu bar that OS X displays does not show my application's menu.

Comment: How are you running your XUL app?

Comment: Alex, from the command line: `/Library/Frameworks/XUL.framework/Versions/Current/xulrunner /path/to/application.ini -no-remote -profile (profile path)`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what was changed, or when they changed it, but this behavior is somewhat documented on MDN.

#### Excerpt from [Getting started with XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/XULRunner/Getting_started_with_XULRunner#Mac):

> On the Mac, before you can run a XULRunner application with everything intact, you must install it using the `--install-app` xulrunner commandline flag. Installing the application creates an OS X application bundle:

The page goes on with some steps for how to do this, but I was never able to get them to work with modern XULRunner versions.

The only way I was ever able to get modern XULRunner versions to fully work is to create the application bundle manually.

In this example, I am going to use [the "hello world" example](https://github.com/matthewkastor/XULRunner-Examples/tree/master/helloWorld) referenced in the MDN docs.

**Step 1:**

Create the following directory structure.

```
hello.app/
    Contents/
        MacOS/
        Resources/
```

**Step 2:**

[Download the version of XULRunner runtime you want](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/) (I'm using 33), and extract the `XUL.framework`.

**Step 3:**

Copy all of the files inside `XUL.framework/Versions/Current/` to `hello.app/Contents/MacOS/`.

Also copy the `dependentlibs.list` into `hello.app/Contents/Resources/`

**Step 4:**

Download [the example files](https://github.com/matthewkastor/XULRunner-Examples/tree/master/helloWorld), and copy the following files and directories to `hello.app/Contents/Resources/`.

- `chrome/`
- `defaults/`
- `application.ini`
- `chrome.manifest`

**Step 5:**

Due to [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109305/how-to-package-a-standalone-xulrunner-app-for-os-x/29242220), the `xulrunner` binary will not automatically find the `application.ini` like it's supposed to. To work around this, we will need a stub loader, like this one I wrote previously.

```
#!/bin/sh

runpath="`dirname "$0"`"
contentsdir="`cd "$runpath"/.. > /dev/null && pwd`"
exec "$runpath/xulrunner" --app "$contentsdir/Resources/application.ini"
```

Create a new file named `hello` at `hello.app/Contents/MacOS/hello`, put the code above inside, and give it executable permissions (`chmod +x hello`).

**Step 6:**

Now we need a `Info.plist` file. Here is one I created based on the [Deploying XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/XULRunner/Deploying_XULRunner_1.8) example. Note that the `CFBundleExecutable` must match the stub loader file name above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>hello</string>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>app_icon.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>net.yourcompany.yourapplication</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>applicationName</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Save this file under `hello.app/Info.plist`.

**Step 7:**

Create a new file named `PkgInfo` at `hello.app/PkgInfo`, and put this text inside.

```
APPL????
```

**Step 8:**

You should now be able to run your application with and menu and doc icon, and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> capabilities. You can open it by Finder, or the command line.

```
$ ./hello.app/Contents/MacOS/hello
```

Comment: I haven't actually gotten it working yet, but it's clear that this is the issue - my application isn't packaged for OS X properly.  When I get around to doing it, I'll make sure to update here that it worked :)