# The application "App.app” can’t be opened

Tags: macos, nsapplication

I'm sure I'm skipping over something, somehow, but I might as well ask. I've been creating an application programmatically, and recently I've been doing some cleaning up to make everything nice, however, recently I'm unable to open my app when the name of .app does not match the name of the executable, even when the correct name for the executable is given in the Info.plist. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182040/the-application-cannot-be-opened-because-its-executable-is-missing

Comment: Wow man, thanks for the help. I guess I didn't find the question because of the title. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Did any of that help?

Comment: Yeah. Although now a ton of system apps have the default application icon now